# Java image paint issue

Tags: java

I have a problem.. I have a image painted on my java applet and a for loop to make the x move up 5 every time.. but it leaves behind the old image for a bit then it will erase it..

```
for(int tohouse = 0; tohouse <= 520; tohouse+=2) {
  try {
    x+=5;
    tohouse+=10;

    if (pos == 0) {
      rectX+=5;
      g.drawImage(picture1,x,150,this);
      pos = 1;
    } else if (pos == 1) {
      rectX+=4;
      g.drawImage(picture2,x,150,this);
      pos = 2;
    } else if (pos == 2) {
      rectX+=5;
      g.drawImage(picture3,x,150,this);
      pos = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Heres a image:

[image]

Comment: which don't you use a switch statement instead of having all those ifs and elses?

Comment: I forgot about those thanks! This is a project for my computer sci AP class.. Im going to fix it to switch statements.

Comment: You need to stop and get a grasp on the basic anatomy of a graphical game.  The absolute first lesson you need to learn is that *rendering* the graphics and *changing the game state* should be independent operations, both in timing and in where the code is placed.  Take a look at http://www.theopavlidis.com/Games/Tutorial_Draft_01/part00.htm (first result I could find).  You simply cannot do animation by putting a for-loop in your paint method.

Comment: Mark this isn't a game.. We have to do a graphic project with animation.

Comment: @Henry: The principles still apply.  Look at Section 4 of the link I provided: Elementary Animation.  (Actually, that might not be a great resource since it doesn't seem to focus on Java.  You might benefit from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html as a start for Swing)

Comment: What method is this code in?  Is it within a component contained in the JApplet?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do animation by looping in your `paintComponent()` or `paint()` method.  Those methods are asking you to paint yourself at a *specific* point in time (i.e. the *current frame*).

Instead, you need to decouple the logic of "moving" your sprite from "rendering" your sprite.  Look for something like this

```
private int x;

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    //draw the images at location x
}

// elsewhere, initialize a javax.swing.Timer to increment x every 15 ms
new Timer(15, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        x += 5;
        repaint();
    }
}.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for(int tohouse = 0; tohouse <= 520; tohouse+=2)
{
    try
    {
        switch(pos){
        case 0:
            rectX+=5;
            g.drawImage(picture1,x,150,this);
            pos = 1;
            break;
        case 1:
              rectX+=4;
                g.drawImage(picture2,x,150,this);
                pos = 2;
            break;
        case 2:
            rectX+=5;
            g.drawImage(picture3,x,150,this);
            pos = 0;
            break;
        default: // add some default behavior here
            break;
        }
    } catch(Exception e){
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell java to repaint the frame.'

Just use `repaint()` on your `JComponent` that the image is in at the end of the for loop. Like this:

```
for(int tohouse = 0; tohouse <= 520; tohouse+=2) {
  try {
  //Process the changes
  }
  component.repaint(); // where component is what the image is added to.
}
```

Comment: That won't work since the logic is *within* his paint method.

Comment: He never said it was inside the `paint()` method. There is really no way for this to work at that point. And even inside of `paint()`, repainting the parent component still works fine (usually).

Comment: No, it won't.  Inside of `paint()`, you are within an event on the event dispatch thread, so all of your `repaint()` calls will get queued up and will only be processed once the method has finished running.